# Converting JSON to XML with namespaces

Tags: python, json, xml, elementtree, xml-namespaces

My JSON data:

```
   {
      "Type":"Baggage",
      "TotalPrice":"INR10080",
      "SupplierCode":"AI",
      "CreateDate":"2023-08-16T06:29:51.961+00:00",
      "ServiceStatus":"Offered",
      "SequenceNumber":"1204",
      "ServiceSubCode":"0C2",
      "SSRCode":"XBAG",
      "IssuanceReason":"C",
      "Key":"PNmYlnTqWDKA0ie2FAAAAA==",
      "AssessIndicator":"MileageOrCurrency",
      "InclusiveOfTax":"true",
      "InterlineSettlementAllowed":"false",
      "GeographySpecification":"Sector",
      "Source":"MCE",
      "ViewableOnly":"false",
      "TotalWeight":"20KG",
      "ProviderCode":"1G",
      "Quantity":"1",
      "BasePrice":"INR9600",
      "ApproximateTotalPrice":"INR10080",
      "ApproximateBasePrice":"INR9600",
      "Taxes":"INR480",
      "IsRepriceRequired":"false",
      "common_v52_0:ServiceData":{
         "BookingTravelerRef":"PNmYlnTqWDKAvie2FAAAAA==",
         "AirSegmentRef":"dnVZlnUqWDKAXC/qFAAAAA==",
         "TravelerType":"ADT",
         "common_v52_0:CabinClass":{
            "Type":"Economy"
         }
      },
      "common_v52_0:ServiceInfo":{
         "common_v52_0:Description":"UPTO44LB_20KG_BAGGAGE"
      },
      "air:TaxInfo":{
         "Category":"K3",
         "Amount":"INR480",
         "Key":"PNmYlnTqWDKA3ie2FAAAAA=="
      },
      "air:EMD":{
         "FulfillmentType":"2",
         "AssociatedItem":"Flight",
         "RefundReissueIndicator":"NonRefundable",
         "Commissionable":"false",
         "Booking":"SSR",
         "FulfillmentTypeDescription":"Associated_to_a_flight_coupon_of_a_ticket"
      },
      "air:FeeApplication":{
         "Code":"4",
         "#text":"Per_travel"
      }
   }
```

And I want XML like this:

```
               <air:OptionalService Type="Baggage" TotalPrice="INR10080" SupplierCode="AI"
                    CreateDate="2023-08-16T06:29:51.961+00:00" ServiceStatus="Offered"
                    SequenceNumber="1204" ServiceSubCode="0C2" SSRCode="XBAG" IssuanceReason="C"
                    Key="PNmYlnTqWDKA0ie2FAAAAA==" AssessIndicator="MileageOrCurrency"
                    InclusiveOfTax="true" InterlineSettlementAllowed="false"
                    GeographySpecification="Sector" Source="MCE" ViewableOnly="false"
                    TotalWeight="20KG" ProviderCode="1G" Quantity="1" BasePrice="INR9600"
                    ApproximateTotalPrice="INR10080" ApproximateBasePrice="INR9600" Taxes="INR480"
                    IsRepriceRequired="false">
                    <common_v52_0:ServiceData BookingTravelerRef="PNmYlnTqWDKAvie2FAAAAA=="
                        AirSegmentRef="dnVZlnUqWDKAXC/qFAAAAA==" TravelerType="ADT">
                        <common_v52_0:CabinClass Type="Economy" />
                    </common_v52_0:ServiceData>
                    <common_v52_0:ServiceInfo>
                        <common_v52_0:Description>UPTO44LB 20KG BAGGAGE</common_v52_0:Description>
                    </common_v52_0:ServiceInfo>
                    <air:TaxInfo Category="K3" Amount="INR480" Key="PNmYlnTqWDKA3ie2FAAAAA==" />
                    <air:EMD FulfillmentType="2" AssociatedItem="Flight"
                        RefundReissueIndicator="NonRefundable" Commissionable="false" Booking="SSR"
                        FulfillmentTypeDescription="Associated to a flight coupon of a ticket" />
                    <air:FeeApplication Code="4">Per travel</air:FeeApplication>
                </air:OptionalService>
```

My code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
def json_to_xml(element, data):
    for key, value in data.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            sub_element = ET.SubElement(element, key)
            json_to_xml(sub_element, value)
        else:
            if ":" in key:
                ns_prefix, local_name = key.split(":")
                print(ns_prefix, local_name)
                sub_element = ET.SubElement(element, "{" + ns_prefix + "}" + local_name)
                sub_element.text = value
            if key == "#text":
                element.text = value
            else:
                element.set(key, value)

root = ET.Element("air:OptionalService")

json_to_xml(root, json_data)

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)

tree.write("test.xml", encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True)
```

And here is the output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<air:OptionalService xmlns:ns0="common_v52_0" Type="Baggage" TotalPrice="INR10080" SupplierCode="AI"
    CreateDate="2023-08-16T06:29:51.961+00:00" ServiceStatus="Offered" SequenceNumber="1204"
    ServiceSubCode="0C2" SSRCode="XBAG" IssuanceReason="C" Key="PNmYlnTqWDKA0ie2FAAAAA=="
    AssessIndicator="MileageOrCurrency" InclusiveOfTax="true" InterlineSettlementAllowed="false"
    GeographySpecification="Sector" Source="MCE" ViewableOnly="false" TotalWeight="20KG"
    ProviderCode="1G" Quantity="1" BasePrice="INR9600" ApproximateTotalPrice="INR10080"
    ApproximateBasePrice="INR9600" Taxes="INR480" IsRepriceRequired="false">
    <common_v52_0:ServiceData BookingTravelerRef="PNmYlnTqWDKAvie2FAAAAA=="
        AirSegmentRef="dnVZlnUqWDKAXC/qFAAAAA==" TravelerType="ADT">
        <common_v52_0:CabinClass Type="Economy" />
    </common_v52_0:ServiceData>
    <common_v52_0:ServiceInfo common_v52_0:Description="UPTO44LB_20KG_BAGGAGE">
        <ns0:Description>UPTO44LB_20KG_BAGGAGE</ns0:Description>
    </common_v52_0:ServiceInfo>
    <air:TaxInfo Category="K3" Amount="INR480" Key="PNmYlnTqWDKA3ie2FAAAAA==" />
    <air:EMD FulfillmentType="2" AssociatedItem="Flight" RefundReissueIndicator="NonRefundable"
        Commissionable="false" Booking="SSR"
        FulfillmentTypeDescription="Associated_to_a_flight_coupon_of_a_ticket" />
    <air:FeeApplication Code="4">Per_travel</air:FeeApplication>
</air:OptionalService>
```

All is good but the problem is in my output, look at the 2nd line in my output - `xmlns:ns0="common_v52_0"`, it's not in my json . one more problem is in my output `<ns0:Description>` it's not right, look at my json it's not `"ns0:Description"` it's `"common_v52_0:Description"`.

Comment: There are problems also with the **wanted** XML. It is ill-formed since there are no declarations for the `air` and `common_v52_0` namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Change this part of the code

```
if "common_v52_0:Description" in key:
 ns_prefix, local_name = key.split(":")
 print(ns_prefix, local_name)
 sub_element = ET.SubElement(element, "{" + ns_prefix + "}" + local_name)
 sub_element.text = value
```

to this

```
if "common_v52_0:Description" in key:
  sub_element = ET.SubElement(element, key)
  sub_element.text = value
```

And this would be the result

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<air:OptionalService Type="Baggage" TotalPrice="INR10080" SupplierCode="AI" CreateDate="2023-08-16T06:29:51.961+00:00" ServiceStatus="Offered" SequenceNumber="1204" ServiceSubCode="0C2" SSRCode="XBAG" IssuanceReason="C" Key="PNmYlnTqWDKA0ie2FAAAAA==" AssessIndicator="MileageOrCurrency" InclusiveOfTax="true" InterlineSettlementAllowed="false" GeographySpecification="Sector" Source="MCE" ViewableOnly="false" TotalWeight="20KG" ProviderCode="1G" Quantity="1" BasePrice="INR9600" ApproximateTotalPrice="INR10080" ApproximateBasePrice="INR9600" Taxes="INR480" IsRepriceRequired="false">
    <common_v52_0:ServiceData BookingTravelerRef="PNmYlnTqWDKAvie2FAAAAA==" AirSegmentRef="dnVZlnUqWDKAXC/qFAAAAA==" TravelerType="ADT">
        <common_v52_0:CabinClass Type="Economy"/>
    </common_v52_0:ServiceData>
    <common_v52_0:ServiceInfo common_v52_0:Description="UPTO44LB_20KG_BAGGAGE">
        <common_v52_0:Description>UPTO44LB_20KG_BAGGAGE</common_v52_0:Description>
    </common_v52_0:ServiceInfo>
    <air:TaxInfo Category="K3" Amount="INR480" Key="PNmYlnTqWDKA3ie2FAAAAA=="/>
    <air:EMD FulfillmentType="2" AssociatedItem="Flight" RefundReissueIndicator="NonRefundable" Commissionable="false" Booking="SSR" FulfillmentTypeDescription="Associated_to_a_flight_coupon_of_a_ticket"/>
    <air:FeeApplication Code="4">Per_travel</air:FeeApplication>
</air:OptionalService>
```

Comment: The result XML is ill-formed since there are no declarations for the `air` and `common_v52_0` namespaces.

Comment: @antocabu here all is ok but the problem is:-        
  
    `<common_v52_0:ServiceInfo common_v52_0:Description="UPTO44LB_20KG_BAGGAGE">
        <common_v52_0:Description>UPTO44LB_20KG_BAGGAGE</common_v52_0:Description>
    </common_v52_0:ServiceInfo>`  .               i don't need this one
    `common_v52_0:Description="UPTO44LB_20KG_BAGGAGE" `
because my json is ,     
   ` "common_v52_0:ServiceInfo":{
         "common_v52_0:Description":"UPTO44LB_20KG_BAGGAGE"
      },`